# Is XRY Forensic Tool able to extract data from iPhones?

Tags: forensics, ios

As far as I know this only DOESN'T work with iPhone 4S and iPad2 / iPad 3, because of the fixed Boot Rom. So, is it no longer possible to brute-force the passcode lock? Can anybody confirm this with some sources? Or does this tool do a jailbreak and make a disk image to extract the data?

Product:
http://www.msab.com/xry/smartphones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you're correct.  For confirmation I had a look at their release notes [here](http://www.msab.com/app-data/downloads/Release_Notes_%28English%29/MSAB_release_notes_6.2_EN.pdf) and on the second to last page at the bottom left it lists the iOS physical support and has a foot note which states (iPhone 3GS, 4 CDMA, 4 GSM, iPod touch 3G and 4 and iPad 1 are supported.)

From that I'd guess that iPhone 4S/iPad 2/iPad 3 are out of reach due to a lack of a current public DFU mode exploit.

Comment: Seems to be slightly overseen by all the press about this topic! Thanks for pointing to the release notes!